# Exception in Release Mode due to ZipFile

Tags: android, zip, android-proguard

I'm using a code snippet to access a Zip File containing APK file . It works fine in Debug Mode, but, throws Exception in Release Mode.

```
 ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
 ZipEntry mft = zip.getEntry("AndroidManifest.xml");
 is = zip.getInputStream(mft);
```

It doesn't make any issue if released in Debug Mode. But, in Release Mode, app gets crashed.

```
 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418c6c08)
 ************ 29072016 ************
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vxeed.xnap/com.vxeed.xnap.forms.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.vxeed.xnap.common.ay.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.vxeed.xnap.forms.MainMenu.onCreate(Unknown Source)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I get rid of this method, it works fine. Do I need to add anything extra in proguard-rules? Please advise. Thanks in advance

Comment: add the lib to progaurd.

Comment: Added this to proguard, but of no use.
-keep class java.util.zip.** {*;}